# ListBoxItems background the same as ListBox ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, bind, listboxitem

I have a WPF `ListBox` `ItemsSource` that's bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>`. The listbox values are:

Blue,
Red,
Green.

I am wanting the Item's background color to match it's value. For example, I want the Blue Item's background color to be Blue, Red to Red, and so forth. I cannot figure out a way to change each `ListBoxItem` since I'm using an `ItemsSource`. How can I bind the `ListBoxItems` background color to these respective values?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Is this a WPF question?

Comment: I am so sorry for that. Yes this is a WPF app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in a couple of ways depending on your use case.

**Solution 1 - using `ValueConverters`:**

You can use `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to style your `ListBoxItem` and then  use a `ValueConverter` to convert `string` values to respective 
 `SolidColorBrushes`.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=., 
                    Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Value Converter:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            var color = value.ToString();
            switch (color)
            {
                case "Blue":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                case "Red":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                case "Green":
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
        return SystemColors.ControlColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Soultion 2 - using `DataTriggers`:**

Again you can use `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to style your `ListBoxItem` and then define several `DataTriggers` to change `ListBoxItem.Background` based on item's value.
This approach is pure XAML:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}" >
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <System:String x:Key="red">Red</System:String>
            <System:String x:Key="green">Green</System:String>
            <System:String x:Key="blue">Blue</System:String>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{StaticResource red}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{StaticResource green}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{StaticResource blue}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

**Edit:**

Assuming dynamically loaded color names are the same as the names of `System.Windows.Media.Colors` then you can replace the `Convert` method in the 1st soultion with this:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var colorStr = value.ToString();
        var color = (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorStr);
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
```

If your color names follow no specific format and they can be anything (i.e. your external file could contain names like "VeryLightGreen" or "PrettyYellow"!) then you should define your own `ColorDictionary` to translate these names to the desired colors:

```
public static class ColorTranslator
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Color> ColorDictionary = LoadColors();
    public static Color FromName(string name)
    {
        return ColorDictionary[name];
    }
    private static Dictionary<string, Color> LoadColors()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

        dictionary.Add("Red", Colors.Red);
        dictionary.Add("Blue", Colors.Blue);
        dictionary.Add("Green", Colors.Green);
        dictionary.Add("VeryLightGreen", Colors.Honeydew);
        dictionary.Add("PrettyYellow", Color.FromArgb(200,255,215,0));

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

And the `Convert` method:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var colorStr = value.ToString();
        var color = ColorTranslator.FromName(colorStr);
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for time. I marked this as an answer because it works as is, but I should've been more descriptive in my OP. It was late night. The colors will actually be loaded dynamically, being read from an external file. If I load those in a ObsColl<string>, how can I modify the Converter? I cant use the Switch since this is done dynamically. Thank you.